# production release suddenly not available anymore

Tags: actions-on-google

We have production release of an Action that was approved in September and worked fine, but suddenly yesterday evening it stopped being available to the public. I can still access it as a developer, but it's not accessible to other users.

It sounds a bit like Google has either marked is as Unhealthy or Taken down, but according to the documentation, we would have received an email, and a notification in the Actions Console, but there is nothing at all. It also doesn't look like the action is unhealthy or has issues.

In addition, and maybe even more confusingly, when now creating a new Alpha release and adding a brand new user, the opt-in link doesn't work for that user either.

We're contacting their support, but I was wondering if anyone has seen something like this before?

Thanks!
Mario.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with actions I maintain. Already created a technical support ticket at https://developers.google.com/actions/support. Still waiting for a reply.

Both actions are made via the Actions SDK, maybe that's related.

Comment: Thanks - I don't believe it's related to the Actions SDK, I'm using Dialogflow. Looks like a widespread issue though, also see the reply below.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a widespread problems with many, but not all, Actions at the moment.

There is further discussion taking place on the support forum at https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/

Comment: It is truly comical behavior. Google is able to push out my notifications. Tapping on them goes no where. Using my invocation name gets a response from Google search.

Answer (score 2):

Please see our published [update](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/diyya2/google_actions_are_down/f43onfu?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

This article has the most assuring argument for us so far:

> Expedia, Audioburst, ABC News Update, Tide, Quaker, Levi’s, Wells Fargo, 
>   Hoover Dry, IBM Watson, AT&T Internet, and a ton of others – those are just a 
>   few that we have found that are no longer working.
>
> ...
>
> Is it likely that this many Google Actions from these high profile
>   organizations all had suddenly run afoul with Google Assistant
>   policies?

https://voicebot.ai/2019/10/18/thousands-of-google-actions-mysteriously-disappeared-from-online-directory-and-are-no-longer-available-google-says-it-could-take-weeks-to-resolve/

Answer (score 0):

Please see our response on Actions availability: https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/diyya2/google_actions_are_down/f43onfu/

Answer (score 0):

Actions Console notification:

"To ensure that Actions are in compliance with our developer policies, some Actions have been temporarily paused and are currently inaccessible to users. Once these Actions are reviewed and verified to comply with our policies, they will become available on the Assistant. We apologize for the inconvenience."

Policy URL
https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/policies/general-policies

Answer (score 0):

Even more official response (not just something posted on Reddit, "The Official Google Developer's Announcement Site"), a response from the aog-support@google.com account:

> Hi developer,
>
> Thank you for your interest in Actions on Google.
>
> I have investigated your Action and can see it is not currently
>   working.
>
> We are in the process of conducting a comprehensive review of Actions
>   to ensure that they meet our developer policies . During this review,
>   some Actions have been paused temporarily.
>
> Once your Action is reviewed and verified, it will become available
>   again on the Assistant. Note this process might take up to a few
>   weeks.
>
> We sincerely apologize for this inconvenience.
>
> Thank you, Yoko Actions on Google Support Team

Yes, that says A FEW WEEKS.